# NameError when running GMRes following FEniCS discretisation

Tags: numpy

I've discretised a diffusion equation with FEniCS as follows:

```
def DiscretiseEquation(h):
    mesh = UnitSquareMesh(h, h)
    V = FunctionSpace(mesh, 'Lagrange', 1)

def on_boundary(x, on_boundary):
    return on_boundary

bc_value = Constant(0.0)
boundary_condition = DirichletBC(V, bc_value, on_boundary)

class RandomDiffusionField(Expression):
    def __init__(self, m, n, element):
        self._rand_field = np.exp(-np.random.randn(m, n))
        self._m = m
        self._n = n
        self._ufl_element = element

    def eval(self, value, x):

        x_index = np.int(np.floor(self._m * x[0]))
        y_index = np.int(np.floor(self._n * x[1]))

        i = min(x_index, self._m - 1)
        j = min(y_index, self._n - 1)

        value[0] = self._rand_field[i, j]

    def value_shape(self):
        return(1, )

class RandomRhs(Expression):

    def __init__(self, m, n, element):
        self._rand_field = np.random.randn(m, n)
        self._m = m
        self._n = n
        self._ufl_element = element

    def eval(self, value, x):

        x_index = np.int(np.floor(self._m * x[0]))
        y_index = np.int(np.floor(self._n * x[1]))

        i = min(x_index, self._m - 1)
        j = min(y_index, self._n - 1)

        value[0] = self._rand_field[i, j]

    def value_shape(self):
        return (1, )

u = TrialFunction(V)
v = TestFunction(V)

random_field = RandomDiffusionField(100, 100, element=V.ufl_element())
zero = Expression("0", element=V.ufl_element())
one = Expression("1", element=V.ufl_element())
diffusion = as_matrix(((random_field, zero), (zero, one)))

a = inner(diffusion * grad(u), grad(v)) * dx
L = RandomRhs(h, h, element=V.ufl_element()) * v * dx

A = assemble(a)
b = assemble(L)
boundary_condition.apply(A, b)
A = as_backend_type(A).mat()
(indptr, indices, data) = A.getValuesCSR()
mat = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=A.size)
rhs = b.array()

#Solving
x = spsolve(mat, rhs)

#Conversion to a FEniCS function
u = Function(V)
u.vector()[:] = x
```

I am running the GMRES solver as normal. The callback argument is a separate iteration counter I've defined.

```
DiscretiseEquation(100)
A = mat
b = rhs
x, info = gmres(A, b, callback = IterCount())
```

The routine returns a NameError, stating that 'mat' is not defined:

```
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-18-e096b2eea097> in <module>()
         1 DiscretiseEquation(200)
   ----> 2 A = mat
         3 b = rhs
         4 x_200, info_200 = gmres(A, b, callback = IterCount())
         5 gmres_res =  closure_variables["residuals"]

   NameError: name 'mat' is not defined
```

As far as I'm aware, it should be defined when I call the DiscretiseEquation function?

Comment: When you ask for help with a error, show enough of the error stack so we know where that error is occurring.  `DiscretiseEquation` doesn't return anything.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, that's intentional. I've edit my original post with the full error message. I intend to use the 'mat' and 'rhs'  values as 'A' and 'b' arguments for the various Krylov solvers (GMRES, CG, MINRES).  This is the error: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e096b2eea097> in <module>()
      1 DiscretiseEquation(200)
----> 2 A = mat
      3 b = rhs
      4 x_200, info_200 = gmres(A, b, callback = IterCount())
      5 gmres_res =  closure_variables["residuals"]

NameError: name 'mat' is not defined

Comment: The big block of code defines `A` and `mat` (as the `csr`).  I don't know where this `A=mat` fits relative to those lines.

Comment: The Krylov solvers are solving for Ax=b. As I understand, the matrix and rhs terms generated by the FEniCS discretisations (mat and rhs) correspond to the 'A' and 'b' arguments to be used in the solvers ie x = gmres(A, b)

Comment: I'm asking about the definition of variables in the Python code, not what the solvers are doing.  `name error` means that at the point where you do `A=mat`, `mat` has not been defined.  Either you are doing that before a `mat=...` statement, or doing it in a different namespace.  This is a plain Python coding problem, not an advanced FEniCS one.

Comment: Ah I see. 'mat' and 'rhs' are defined as part of the DiscretiseEquation function. The function is called first, then the solver.